How would you format to be cleaner and explain the steps better? Do I have any no no's in my latex?
How would you format this to be cleaner and explain the steps better? Do I have any no no's in my latex? Pretty much complete newbie in latex and want to start moving my notes into it but it seems like a herculean effort.
\begin{align}
    &{(8x^3)\textcolor{red}{(x+5)^{-7}}(3x+1)^{3 \over 4} - \textcolor{red}{(2x^2)}(x+5)^{-5} \textcolor{red}{(3x+1)^{-{1 \over 4}}}\over (x+5)^{10}(3x+1)^2}\\\\

    \text{This results in:}\\
    &{\textcolor{blue}{(2x^2)}\textcolor{green}{(x+5)^{-7}}\textcolor{red}{(3x+1)^{-{1 \over 4}}}[\textcolor{blue}{(4x)}\textcolor{red}{(3x+1)} - \textcolor{green}{(x+5)^2}] \over (x+5)^{10}(3x+1)^2}\\\\
    
    \\\text{expand right side:}\\\\
    &{(2x^2)(x+5)^{-7}{(3x+1)^{-{1 \over 4}}}[\textcolor{red}{(12^2x+4x)} - \textcolor{green}{(x^2+10x+25)}] \over (x+5)^{10}(3x+1)^2}\\\\

    \text{distribute the negative and like terms:}\\
    &{(2x^2)(x+5)^{-7}{(3x+1)^{-{1 \over 4}}}(\textcolor{red}{11x^2-6x-25}) \over (x+5)^{10}(3x+1)^2}\\\\
    \text{bring downs the negative exponents that are factors:}\\
    
    &{(2x^2)(11x^2-6x-25) \over (x+5)^{10}\textcolor{green}{(x+5)^7}(3x+1)^2\textcolor{green}{{(3x+1)^{1 \over 4}}}}\\\\
    \text{Result:}\\
        &{(2x^2)(11x^2-6x-25) \over \textcolor{green}{(x+5)^{17}}\textcolor{green}{{(3x+1)^{9 \over 4}}}}\\\\
\end{align}


Welcome to TeX.SE.  It's actually not quite clear what you have, because you haven't included the necessary packages so that this compiles, and blank lines aren't allowed in the most common align environment.  The abundance of \text and \\  is suspicious.  But the outright NO! is \over.  It's just about the worst aspect of TeX.  Use \frac instead.

There's actually a truly commendable aspect to your code: You do not use \left and \right to auto-size all round parentheses and square brackets. I mention this because, in my experience, the overuse -- and, frankly, inappropriate use -- of \left and \right is one of the most common problematic coding habits of TeX and LaTeX newbies.


Do I have any no no's in my latex [code]?

Short answer: Yes.
Longer answer:

All-blank lines are not allowed in any of the multi-row math environments of the amsmath package.

Learn about the \intertext macro of the amsmath package.

Never use {... \over ...} notation in a LaTeX document. Instead, use \frac{...}{...} notation.

Familiarize yourself with inline-fraction notation -- especially for "small" terms in superscript and subscript positions.

There cannot be a (justifiable!) need for \\\\ ("double \\").

Use \textcolor for text-mode material -- and \mathcolor for math-mode material. Well, \textcolor sort of does work for most math material; however, there are also cases when it doesn't. Hence my recommendation to use \mathcolor for math-mode material.

To simplify writing and especially debugging LaTeX code, I find it helpful to keep input lines short. And, do try to be consistent in the way you employ indentation of lines to create visual grouping. See the code below for an example of this approach to coding.

Don't overdo it with using curly braces -- { and } -- to create visual groups. They quickly do nothing but create clutter.

The color green is hard to read on-screen. I suggest you load the xcolor package with the option dvipsnames and use Green -- or, really, any darker shade of green -- instead of green. See section 4 of the user guide of the xcolor package for a list of named colors that become available by specifying the package options dvipsnames, svgnames, and x11names.

Final piece of advice: If there's any chance at all that you'll be doing a fair amount of math typesetting in the months and years ahead, do take the time to study the user guide of the amsmath package. It'll be time very well spent.


P.S. I focused on the typesetting aspects of the job at hand, but didn't check your mathematical derivations for correctness. :-)  I also didn't attempt to come up with an easier-to-fathom color scheme; I can't say I understand why you assigned red, blue, and green to various terms in various rows.

\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align' environment and '\intertext'  macro
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} % for '\mathcolor' macro 
                                % 'dvipsnames' for 'Green' named color

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
&\frac{(8x^3)
       \mathcolor{red}{(x+5)^{-7}}
       (3x+1)^{3/4} - 
       \mathcolor{red}{(2x^2)}
       (x+5)^{-5} 
       \mathcolor{red}{(3x+1)^{-1/4}}}%
      {(x+5)^{10}(3x+1)^2} \\
\intertext{This can be rewritten as:}
&\frac{\mathcolor{blue}{(2x^2)}
       \mathcolor{Green}{(x+5)^{-7}}
       \mathcolor{red}{(3x+1)^{-1/4}}
       [\mathcolor{blue}{(4x)}
        \mathcolor{red}{(3x+1)} - 
        \mathcolor{Green}{(x+5)^2}]}%
      {(x+5)^{10}(3x+1)^2} \\
\intertext{expand square bracket terms:}
&\frac{(2x^2)(x+5)^{-7}(3x+1)^{-1/4}
       [\mathcolor{red}{(12^2x+4x)} - 
        \mathcolor{Green}{(x^2+10x+25)}]}%
      {(x+5)^{10}(3x+1)^2} \\
\intertext{distribute negative and like terms:}
&\frac{(2x^2)(x+5)^{-7}(3x+1)^{-1/4}
       (\mathcolor{red}{11x^2-6x-25})}%
      {(x+5)^{10}(3x+1)^2} \\
\intertext{bring down negative-exponent terms that are factors:}
&\frac{(2x^2)(11x^2-6x-25)}%
      {(x+5)^{10}
       \mathcolor{Green}{(x+5)^7}
       (3x+1)^2
       \mathcolor{Green}{(3x+1)^{1/4}}} \\
\intertext{Result:}
    &\frac{(2x^2)(11x^2-6x-25)}%
          {\mathcolor{Green}{(x+5)^{17}}
           \mathcolor{Green}{(3x+1)^{9/4}}}
\end{align}

\end{document}

